# Change BooleanField value when now within time interval

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model:

```
class Track(models.Model):
     act_time_start = models.DateField(null=True)
     act_time_finish = models.DateField(null=True)
     active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

What is the best practice of making `active = True` when now is between `act_time_start` and `act_time_finish`?
Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you'd specify that in the Model, but rather in the view or wherever your logic to persist to the database is

Comment: Thanks for reply! User make a record and let this record be visible between act_time_start and act_time_finish. Active just show me, that datatime.now fit that time interval. Do you think it's better to move it away from Model?

Comment: Check my answer, I used `today` because I see in your models, you use `DateField`, with a comparison between DateField and `datetime.now()`, python would raise *Exception Error*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work, override the `save()` method  of Model

```
import datetime 

NOW = datetime.date.today()
# it can be datetime.datetime.now() in case of using models.DateTimeField


class Track(models.Model):
    act_time_start = models.DateField(null=True) # Use DateTimeField for comparison with date and time
    act_time_finish = models.DateField(null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.pk is None:
            # Ensure that act_time_start and act_time_finish have date value
            # i.e: if isinstance(self.act_time_start,datetime.date)
            # 
            if self.act_time_start < NOW and NOW > self.act_time_finish:
                self.active = True
        super(Track, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank for reply! Can you please describe me the way it works? Does that method check time everyday if we use datatime.date.today()? I just try to find the smootest and clearest way. How about Celery tasks? Is it safe?

Comment: Each time that you save an object, it will set it to True or False like you want, if you want to modify as you edit your models, remove the line `if self.pk is None`. So if you want to hit the all the data per a specific time, Celery can do it, just tell Celery to loop through your models, and my code above will set it True/False the way you want